# Restrict C++ Template argument to be inside a namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Is there a way to restrict a template type to be part of a certain namespace?

```
namespace AAA
{
struct CLS_1
{};
}

struct CLS_2
{};

foo<CLS_1>(); // This is Ok
foo<CLS_2>(); // Will not compile - CLS_2 is not inside template AAA
```

I tried something like this:

```
template<class T> requires requires(T t) {AAA::T;}
void foo()
{}
```

but that did not compile.
Is there a (simple) way to do so?

Comment: Yes, you can (to some degree) abuse ADL to do that (although not strictly in full generality), but it seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: There isn't a lot of point to this. Anybody can declare anything to be inside a namespace, unless things have changed since I were a lad ;-)

Comment: I disagree. the idea is not to hack this code but to define a correct use of it .

Comment: @DuduArbel You disagree with what?

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit the fact that argument-dependent lookup will find functions in the same namespace as the argument. Here's how:

```cpp
namespace AAA {
struct CLS_1 {};

// add a helper function to namespace AAA
template <typename T>
// const volatile& can bind to any value category and cv qualification
void namespace_aaa_membership_tester(const volatile T&) {
    // This function should never be instantiated.
    // Note that older compilers don't handle static_assert(false) correctly,
    // and you have to make the condition dependent on T.
    static_assert(false); // (1)
}
} // namespace AAA
struct CLS_2 {};

// define a concept; this could be used as a type constraint for functions
template <typename T>
concept in_aaa = requires (T& t) {
    // this expression is only valid for AAA::T
    namespace_aaa_membership_tester(t);
};

int main() {
    static_assert(in_aaa<AAA::CLS_1>); // OK
    static_assert(!in_aaa<CLS_2>);     // OK
    // Known issue with ADL: this also passes.
    static_assert(in_aaa<std::vector<AAA::CLS_1>>); // OK
    // Known issue with type aliases: namespace of the type alias
    // is irrelevant. This could be considered good or bad.
    using type = AAA::CLS_1;
    static_assert(in_aaa<type>); // OK
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8YfGasMKv)*

#### Notes

Note that this wouldn't pass for a type `AAA::BBB::CLS_1`, as only surrounding namespace is considered by ADL, not all parent namespaces recursively. I believe it is impossible to check whether `AAA::arbitrary_namespace::CLS_1` is in `AAA`.

Also keep in mind that anyone can put anything they want into a namespace, so there is very little that can be gained by knowing whether a type `T` is in `AAA` in practice.
A more robust way of giving certain classes "extra privileges" is by making them `friend`s of some `AAA::Privileged` class.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> It's okay to have templates that can never be instantiated as the result of `static_assert(false)` due to a special case in [[temp.res.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.1).

Comment: In my usecase - only one namespace with classes in it.

Comment: can not use this solution. I don't want to contaminate the namespace

Comment: @DuduArbel You cannot prevent anyone from contaminating the namespace. That's the whole problem with your envisaged solution.

Comment: @DuduArbel I believe there is no other way because the language doesn't have static reflections and doesn't give you any way of checking what namespace something is located in. The only possible hack is to use abuse ADL. If you make the name of the function long and obscure enough, then you're not polluting the namespace in any significant way.

Comment: @Quimby no; `static_assert` is exempt from this rule. See https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.1 I've updated the answer to explain that.

Comment: This work a bit better than one probably wants [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ezbqP3f6Y).

Comment: not sure if the way how this plays with type aliases is a plus or a minus. https://godbolt.org/z/hGerT7b4M. You can easily get into the situation where `AAA::CLS_2` is defined and refers to `::CLS_2` but the concept is not satisfied for `AAA::CLS_2`. Perhaps thats what OP wants, but I find it totally confusing.

Comment: @Quimby: rule has been added/modified in C++23.

Comment: @Jarod42 note that the change in https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2593r1.html applies retroactively to older standards too; it's considered a language defect that `static_assert(false)` wouldn't work as expected. So just to be clear, it boils down to the compiler version; the behavior isn't any different between C++23 and C++20.